# Subdomain is not working

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I just finished setting up my multisite. However the subdomain is not working.

I believe I followed every step necessary to create a subdomain network for wordpress multiste.

I also have created a wildcard subdomain

```
*.yofnel.com
```

That points to /public_html

I dont know what to do now. Please help.

Comment: If you believe you followed all the steps, then you should list in your questions which steps you've taken.  Did you do "Network Activate" from wp-admin after setting `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: Yes I did that. My main website is working. I was able to create sites too but these created sites are not working. When I visit them(http://testing.yofnel.com/) it just says "Oops! Google Chrome could not find testing.yofnel.com"

Answer (score 1):

After setting `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` in your `wp-config.php`  file and doing "Network Activate", you need to copy some new constants to your `wp-config.php` file. Are the following constants definitions there?

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```